# Returning complex values from JavaScript in Unity WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, emscripten

I'm using Unity3D's WebGL support, and I'm trying to call out to a JavaScript library from my code in order to perform some computation. The return type of the function I'm trying to call is a JavaScript object. [The Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html) provides information on how to call functions from JavaScript and return primitive values:

```cs
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern string StringReturnValueFunction();
```

So the way I'm currently using this is to convert the object into JSON, pass it into Unity, and then deserialize it. As you might imagine, there are some performance problems with this approach.

What I really want to do is directly return a JavaScript object and access it from C#:

```cs
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern MyStruct StructReturnValueFunction();
```

Is there some efficient way to map a JavaScript object so it can be accessed from managed C# on the emscripten side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik it is not possible.

---

Have a look at [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/trying-to-share-float-array-between-c-and-webgl-browser-javascript.394861/).

There are these two posts that are pretty much exactly what you are asking:

> dansav
>
> Is there any way to share user created classes between unity c# and webgl javascript? I was reading about Emscripten Embind which seems to offer a solution for sharing classes between c++ and javascript. Is it possible to make a jslib class?
>
> https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html

And the answer from UnityTechnologies

> No, you can not use this mechanism directly for C#. As has been noted before, C# scripts are first transformed into C++ code using il2cpp. There is no direct correspondence between C# classes and their generated C++ representations, and even if there was, it would be Unity version specific, and therefore you would not be able to rely on it. It should be however possible to achieve something like this using C plugin.
>
> Note that mentioned C++ binding does not involve sharing of the actual class objects or memory. When you use instance.x=20 in JavaScript from the above example, you do not modify the x value on the heap directly, but instead implicitly execute the JavaScript setter function of the instance, which then transfers your value 20 to the binded &MyClass::setX C++ function. So this only looks like sharing while in fact this is copying. This mechanism has been implemented for programming convenience and you should not expect any performance boost when using it. Moreover, you can implement the same accessor functions for your C# classes yourself (in which case you will also have to add the binding code to the JavaScript manually).

---

However, it is from 2016 .. things might have changed but afaik still `string` and numeric types and arrays of those are the only directly possible return types.